# Google IOT device on webhooks & post

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Is there any way to create your own google IOT device based on webhooks and POST-request? Without using firebase, IFTT, node.js

Samples that Google are very poor, they don`t show all steps of creating your own app, they just showing how to deploy "their sample"

I tried to make action with dialogflow & webhook, it was pretty simple. Just processed JSON in POST request to Azure function.

But when I try to create IOT device, its ask me for fulfilment url and it does not even tries to reach that address. I read about action.device.sync, action.device.execute, it just does not communicate with the specified address, giving simulator some voice command doesn`t affect at all. Are there any ways to create IOT device to work with POST-requests & web-hooks?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends.

There are many different ways to do server-device communication: web sockets, local servers, hub/local control, polling, MQTT, and likely many others. All of these solutions have trade-offs, and work in particular circumstances. Depending on exactly what IoT device you want to build, its requirements and technical specs, and what cloud providers you are using, you may identify what works best.

If you run the sample, you'll see it is sending JSON requests to a server and expect JSON responses back. This is must like Dialogflow & a webhook. In this case, the smart home platform communicates solely with the server.

Your server can then communicate with the device in any way that you want. I'm not too familiar with Azure offerings. It might have an MQTT service as well, or some other sort of push notification service you might be able to use.

If you're seeing simulator issues, you may need to make sure your authentication is set up correctly, and you'll need to first complete account linking on your phone before you can use the simulator.